# Two notions of boundedness in metrizable topological vector space.

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In a metrizable topological vector space  $X $ with the metric $d $, a subset A is said to be bounded if it can be absorbed by any neighbourhood of $0$  and a subset A is said to be d-bounded if its diameter with respect to the metric d is finite. Boundedness always implies d-boundedness, but the converse is not true.

I am looking for a condition for which d-boundedness implies boundedness. In the Wikipedia [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator), in the section "Topological vector spaces'', there is a statement, "The two notions of boundedness coincide for locally convex spaces''. But there is no reference for it there. Can somebody give some reference or some hint to prove this statement?

Comment: Do you want to see it in it the most general case, or is the Boundlessness between Banach spaces enough?

Comment: In the general case.

Comment: What two notions of boundedness are supposed to be equivalent? metric and linear space? That's false.

Comment: Boundedness and d-boundedness for a subset in a metrizable topological vector space. I edited my question.

Comment: @Infinity $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is a counterexample in the usual metric. A locally convex space with a bounded neighbourhood is normable which this space isn’t.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example is $\mathbb{R}$ with the metrics $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$. These two metrics define the same topology. The definition of bounded with absorption is a topological property and does not depend on which metric you choose. $d$-boundedness depends on the metric.